Django app on Vercel behaving differently when the DEBUG's value is changed
When I deploy a Django app on Vercel with DEBUG = False, it's showing "maximum unzipped size exceeded," but when I deploy the same Django app with DEBUG = True, it's working fine. Why so?
This is the main problem. If more context is required, I will be more than happy to share.

Django uses compression and caching, which can increase the size of files. Vercel has limits on the uncompressed size of files.When DEBUG = False, Django compresses files, which can paradoxically increase the uncompressed size due to the way compression algorithms work
